# How to send and receive with Python and socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I want to send to a server that his a raspberry pi and a client that works on Windows. The problem is that the client can connect, but after that, it only sends the message when I close the socket. Going further maybe the cause can be that I use portforwarding.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScxsD.png)

My server code

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the address given on the command line
server_address = ('', 1234)
sock.bind(server_address)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % sock.getsockname()
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'client connected:', client_address
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                break
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

and the client

```
# coding: utf-8

import socket

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

socket.connect(("", 1234))

user_tab=input("What do you want to send?")
data=(str(user_tab))
print(data)
data = data.encode("utf-8")
socket.sendall(data)

print("send all")

d=socket.recv(128)
socket.close()
host, port =('', 1234)

socket.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't see that problem what you talking about.

Client code:

```
user_tab = input("What do you want to send?")
data = (str(user_tab))
print(data)
data = data.encode("utf-8")
socket.sendall(data)
print("send all")

user_tab = input("something else?")

d=socket.recv(1024)
socket.close()
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EZPV.png)

Comment: do you use portfowarding it's maybe what block the code, I will try without portfowarding to see if it's what blocks to send the text.

Comment: maybe it's because the serveur his on another computer?

Comment: Maybe. You can run this code on the same computer. Simply change IP to 127.0.0.1 for that.

Comment: i try but i don't know why when the client and the serveur are not on the same computer it doesn't work. Do you know how to do for that it works when the client and the serveur are not on the same computer.

Comment: @raphael no, i don't know.. check you firewall or antivirus software, router may be too. there are many reasons for that.

Comment: thanks, I already try with turning off the firewall but not the antivirus.

Comment: hello, it has been a long time but i think that this link can be helpful. do you think that he have the same problem than me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59436409/cant-send-data-with-socket-and-portfowarding-with-out-clothing-it-i-need-to-se